# Sentry is not working on my live server

Tags: php, laravel, cartalyst-sentry

I am using `"cartalyst/sentry": "2.1.*"` in my laravel 4.2

All things are working fine on my local server, but I am unable to use sentry on live server.

My issue is that I am unable to get Sentry user on routes.php

```
$credentials = array("email" => $postData["email"], "password" => $postData["password"]);

        // Authenticate the user
        $user = Sentry::authenticate($credentials, false);
        if ($user) {
            // its redirecting fine for both usres
            if($user->hasAccess('admin')){
              return Redirect::to('admin/index');                   
            }
            if($user->hasAccess('Advertiser')){
              return Redirect::to('advertiser');
            }
```

Things are working fine here, I am able to get user by `Sentry::getUser()` and also check the user access, and its also redirecting to the particular route.

But on my routes.php

```
Route::get('advertiser', ['as' => 'advertiser' function () {
// I am not getting user here, and it redirects user to index route
if (!Sentry::check()) {
    return Redirect::to('index');
} 
else {
    return View::make('advertiser-home');
}
}]);
```

I have checked a lot, but did not find sentry working on any page.

Please help me.

Comment: No error messages? Just the Sentry::check() always returns false?

Comment: Instead of checking if the user is authenticated directly in the route, why not create a filter and apply that to the route.

Comment: Did you checked your application logs, at `app/storage/logs/laravel.log`?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did anyone found anything? My code is on vps and its not logging anything. Need Help

Answer (score 0):

This was causing due to caching. What I did was ran following commands:

```
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:clear
```

With these commands my `debugbar` and `Sentry` both started working. In case still you face any issue, try

```
php artisan view:clear
```

I am using Laravel 5.2 and these commands helped to get both working.

Comment: Be sure to run the upper two commands on any deploy you make to your production site, or you'll have a bad time in general